# how to add checkboxes in extjs tagfield

Tags: extjs

I was able to create a multiselect combobox with Select all feature using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dFEsc/16/ ,working combobox image is  shown below. I want to create a tagfield with checkboxes now.
Below code is not working. Infact the whole tpl doesnt work.

```
expand: {
 fn: function() {
var dropdown = Ext.get(id).dom.parentElement;
var container = Ext.DomHelper.insertBefore(dropdown, '<div id="'+id+'-container"></div>', true);
toolbar.render(container);
},
single: true
}
```

Is there any way I can apply the same code to an extjs tagfield [image]?

Comment: ExtJs has a proper tag field with real tags, what's the point in having checkboxes?

Comment: This is not how the Tagfield works, you are trying to transform the TagField back into a ComboBox with MultiSelect. My advice to you is to create your own Component extending the ComboBox and use MultiSelect (this is what TagField does).

Comment: Thanks Guilherme got your point. I created a plugin for combobox whose image has been attached in the question. It is working correctly, the issue is I have made use of multiselect property which has been deprecated in extjs. It may cause issues in the near future

Comment: If you check the TagField source code (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Tag.js.html#Ext.form.field.Tag) it also uses `multiSelect: true`. The config has been deprecated so people are encouraged to use the TagField, but for your needs, you should stick with the ComboBox.

Comment: Ok Guilherme thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Guilherme said.

In case the tagfield with combobox has been requested by your customer(and can not be otherwise) here is a suggestion (although a little elaborate).

Note: this only creates a visual effect for the user, since tagfield does not need this to work as expected

```
{
xtype: 'tagfield',
fieldLabel: 'MyTagfield',
name: 'name',
valueField: 'id_name',
displayField: 'name',
queryMode: 'local',
bind: {
    store: '{mystore}'
},
emptyText: '',
delimiter: '',
submitEmptyText: false,
allowBlank: false,
allowOnlyWhitespace: true, // this is important
enableKeyEvents: true,
multiSelect: true,
selectOnFocus: false, 
editable: false,
stacked: true, // better with this config
listConfig: {
       tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',           
        '<div role="option" class="x-boundlist-item" style="padding-left: 5px">',
        '<img src="' + Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '"class="chkCombo-default-icon chkCombo"/> {name}</div>',
        '</tpl>'

},
```

You need the checked e unchecked gif in your images resources folder

And you need the following css:

```
.x-boundlist-item img.chkCombo {
   background: transparent url('../resources/images/unchecked.gif');
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
 }

 .x-boundlist-selected img.chkCombo{
    background: transparent url('../resources/images/checked.gif');
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
 }
```

I hope it helps.

Edited: I only tested this solution with EXTJS 5.1

Comment: Thanks josei for ur reply. Actually i had applied the same in my combobox(image in this problem) and it works there, however in tagfield in extjs version 6.0.1 there is some issue in template rendering and it doesn't work. In earlier version and also higher versions this works fine. But I need it in version 6.0.1

Comment: You're right; I tested it now with extjs 6.0.1 and it did not work